# Get only the grandchildren, not the direct children of page/current page?

Tags: php, child-pages, pages

I know javascript pretty well now but I am new to php and wordpress theme building. I have searched a fair bit and can't find a solution to something that seems like a pretty simple task, all I would like to accomplish is get all the grandchildren of a page only, not the direct children, like so:

**Portfolio**

- child 1

  - grandchild 1A
  - grandchild 1B
- child 2

  - grandchild 2A
  - grandchild 2B

My page is "Portfolio" and I would like to "get_pages" but only the ones that are grandchildren of "Portfolio, so in this case it would return only: -"grandchild 1A", "grandchild 1B", "grandchild 2A", "grandchild 2B".

any suggestions?

Comment: I think I came to the same conclusions, the "get_pages" was just to illustrate :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no native way to do this AFAIK. The easiest way will be:

- to simply query all the pages in the hierarchy of the page ID passed
- then return all the parent ID's (*$post_parent property of the post object*) from all pages in an array
- loop through the pages and compare the page ID against the ID's in the parent ID's array
- any page which has its ID in the parent ID's array we will simply skip and exclude
- any page which ID is not in the parent ID array, we will use this to build a new array, these pages will be the lowest level pages

The easiest will be to build our own custom function which we can call in any page template. Here is the function:

```
function get_lowest_level_pages( $page_id = '' )
{
    // Check if we have a page id, if not, return false
    if ( !$page_id )
            return false;

    // Validate the page id
    $page_id = filter_var( $page_id, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT );

    // Check if this is a page, if not, return false
    if ( !is_page() )
        return false;

    // Get all pages in hierarchy of the current page
    $args = [
        'child_of' => $page_id,
    ];
    $q = get_pages( $args );

    // Check if there are pages, if not, return false
    if ( !$q )
        return false;

    // Use wp_list_pluck to get all the post parents from all return pages
    $parents = wp_list_pluck( $q, 'post_parent' );
    // Set the $new__page_array variable that will hold grandchildren/lowest level pages
    $new__page_array = [];

    // Loop through all the pages
    foreach ( $q as $page_object ) {
        // Simply skip any page if it has child page
        if ( in_array( $page_object->ID, $parents ) )
            continue;

        // Create a new array holding only grandchild pages
        $new__page_array[] = $page_object;
    }

    return $new__page_array; 
}
```

You can then use it as follow: (*Just remember to pass the id of the parent page you need to get the grand children from*)

```
$page_id = get_queried_object_id(); // Returns the current page ID
$q = get_lowest_level_pages( $page_id );

if ( $q ) {
    foreach ( $q as $post ) {
        setup_postdata( $post );

        the_title();

    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: Okay a whole bunch of information there, so I store the functions in my function.php, because I learned that was the best way to go about that, then the "use", I in this case use in my "page-portfolio.php, bit where do I pass the id? I know the ID to be 10, is there a way I can pass witht the slug name isntead?

Comment: Just use my last block of code, `get_queried_object_id()` will return the ID of the page `page-portfolio.php`, no need to pass the slug. Passing the slug will lead to other headaches and will slow the code down even more.

Comment: Any luck on this. Saw your update over on [so]. My code works, so if you have issues, it should be on your side. Let me know if you need any assistance here

Answer (score 1):

Use [`get_page_children`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_children)

```
$all_wp_pages = get_all_page_ids();

// Get the page as an Object
$portfolio = get_page_by_title('Portfolio');

// Filter through all pages and find Portfolio's children
$portfolio_children = get_page_children($portfolio->ID, $all_wp_pages);

foreach ($portfolio_children as $child) {

    $post_data = array('child_of' => $child->ID);
    $grandchild = get_pages($post_data);
}

// echo what we get back from WP to the browser
echo '<pre>' . print_r($grandchild, true) . '</pre>';
```

Comment: I tried using your code, then added this, to loop through: 'foreach( $portfolio_children as $page ) { echo $page->post_title; }' But it returns the children also, so Child1 and Child2, This I could achieve with get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID,parent' => $post->ID,  ));I am only looking for the grandchildren.

Comment: @PieterGoosen You are right. Code is from [codex.wordpress.org](http://codex.wordpress.org)

Comment: @WilliamLarsenBang check updated code

Comment: nothing prints?

Comment: U get no data ? I updated the code again

Comment: I can see that it's printing <pre></pre> in my parent div, but not content in it? Tried the new also.

Comment: Check in the `posts` table (db), if you got the child ID as `child_of` or  as `post_parent` in grandchild ID.

Comment: okay, where is posts table?

Comment: In your database `wp_posts`

Comment: I don't see anywhere that is called wp_posts, checked my wordpress folder?

Comment: Connect to your database (propably phpmyadmin) on your host and check the database you set for wordpress installation. If you havent changed the table prefix, you should see a `wp_posts` table in there. A simple query will get you the pages you are looking for.

Comment: I tried going here? http://localhost/wordpress/wp_posts

Comment: You are local. So go to `localhost/phpmyadmin` (you can see XAMPP Panel)

Answer (score 0):

This for so you can get an idea, havent tested this code but maybe you should try.

```
<?php

    $args = array(
    'post_parent' => 0, //post parent id
    'post_type'   => 'any', 
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'any' 
); 
    $childen = get_children( $args, OBJECT );

    foreach($children as $child){

      $args = array(
    'post_parent' => $child->ID,
    'post_type'   => 'any', 
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'any' 
); 
      $grand_children[] = get_children($args, OBJECT);
}
```

maybe you can try like that.

Comment: Your code makes no sense at all unfortuantely. What is `$args` and `$output`

Comment: if you dont know can you google the get_children function or you are looking for spoon feeding. anyway here is the ref. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children

Comment: Listen here my friend, your crappy attitude is not welcomed. Please see [answer] and rather learn how to add a proper answer than just a lot of rubbish that does not make sense.

Comment: Okay I can't really make sense of this piece of code, would I have to declare $args and $output first?

Comment: That is why I made a heading of "havent tested this code but maybe you should try' so that he could have an idea. Then from that on he could google what is get_children function is, and before you tell me its make no sense you should know what I am referring to. Where in my statement is rubbish attitude?

Comment: @WilliamLarsenBang i edited the code, maybe it make sense now, but if it is still not its fine :)

Comment: I tried, didn't work :(